# How can I trigger a single deployment hook from a matrix in github?

Tags: github, github-actions

So I have this matrix

```
name: test

on: [create, push]

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        context: [test, pgtest]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: docker compose
        run: |
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.${{ matrix.context }}.yml up -d
          docker ps
      - name: install liquibase
        run: |
          wget --quiet https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/v3.8.4/liquibase-3.8.4.tar.gz
          wget --quiet https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.9.jar
          mkdir -p liquibase
          tar --extract --file liquibase-*.tar.gz --directory liquibase
      - name: wait for dbs
        run: |
          set -x
          wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh
          chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
          ./wait-for-it.sh localhost:5432
          docker pull postgres:alpine
          isReady() {
            docker run --network host --rm postgres:alpine pg_isready \
              --host localhost --dbname test --username postgres --timeout 30
          }
          until isReady
          do
            sleep 1
          done
      - name: db migration
        run: |
          ./liquibase/liquibase --defaultsFile=liquibase-${{ matrix.context }}.properties update \
          || ( docker-compose logs && exit 1)
```

the matrix's only point is to test different contexts for liquibase. I don't actually want to create different binaries for each matrix or anything like that. I see matrix as kind of a thread fork, but I don't know how to join at the end so I can kick off a single deployment event.

I think that running on [`check_run.completed`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events) should allow me to do this, but... [that event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#checkrunevent) doesn't seem to trigger either.

how can I kick off a single deployment event after the entire matrix has run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctly you can just add another job that depends on the `build` job containing the matrix using `needs`. It will wait for all the matrix jobs to finish before running `deploy`.

```
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        context: [test, pgtest]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Tests
        run: echo "Testing ${{ matrix.context }}"

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        run: echo "Deploying"
```

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972352/what-does-the-http-request-to-trigger-a-deployment-event-look-like/59977326#59977326) completes the solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of accomplishing this:

1. Split the current matrix into two jobs and have the deployment hook depend on the `test` job. This way `test` and `pgtest` run in parallel and when `test` finishes the deployment will start. The problem with this approach is code readbility and maintenance as you'll have the code completely duplicated unless you actually encapsulated it into an action itself, extreme overkill.
2. Run the deployment hook as a conditional last step of `test`. This seems the best option given the question you've asked, but there might be situations where this itself is not optimal.

The last step for solution (2) would look something like this

```
- name: Deployment
  if: matrix.context == 'test'
  run: echo "Do something"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm... when you say have the deployment hook depend on the test job, what do you mean? I presume this is somehow different from just doing another serial run in option 2.

neither of these are ideal though as it doesn't wait for *both* to finish successfully, I think. github suggests there's a way to do that, but I don't see it.

Comment: well you've edited the question in a way that changed the problem completely from `after the test matrix has run` to `after the entire matrix has run?`. If that's what you want the other answer posted here by @peterevans is the correct one.