# What does the http request to trigger a deployment event look like?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to fire a [deployment event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deploymentevent) but I don't really understand the http request I need to send in order for it to work. What does minimal request look like? `curl -vvv` is good, since I'll be doing it with shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you linked is generated when a deployment occurs. So I think what you actually want to do is create a deployment?

To create a deployment during a GitHub actions step with curl it should look something like the following. See the [documentation here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/#parameters-1) for details of other parameters you might want to send via the API.

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create deployment
        run: |
          curl -XPOST 'https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/deployments' \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.ant-man-preview+json" \
            --data '{ "ref": "master" }'
```

Alternatively, there are a number of third party actions on the GitHub Marketplace specifically for creating deployments. [See here](https://github.com/marketplace?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=actions&query=deployment).

Comment: I had to change this curl a bit for interpolation
`          SERVER_ENV=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -f1,2 -d"/" --complement)
          curl --silent --trace-ascii --fail -XPOST "https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/deployments" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.ant-man-preview+json" \
            --data "{ \"ref\": \"$GITHUB_REF\",\"environment\":\"$SERVER_ENV\", \"auto-merge\":\"false\", \"required_contexts\":[]}"`